# apple macos external keyboard right shift and up arrow not work

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have "Macbook Pro" where everything goes great

because of my body spine I have to use now big "[Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver?fnode=56https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver?fnode=56)"

everything works great but not a little but very important function - keystroke <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> NOT work to "select whole above line" - but keystroke <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> works OK

btw that "right shift" with another combination work well

**Q any idea what and where set?**

Answer (score -1):

Probably that there's no 'shortcut' assigned to what you are trying.
You can verify this when you open your 'keyboard setting' and go to the third tab as in the screenshot.
[image: Keyboard Settings]

Check in the different lists if you find the non working combination or not, and if you dont, add it to the function you want it to do.

Comment: thx but - "shift+arrow" is just "select text" - there is no special function

Comment: I just tested the combination you gave and it does nothing on my system. Look for the function you want it to perform in the lists on the left side, when you found the function, assign the keys to it.

Comment: yap with "right shift" it does nothing, with "left" without problem select above line of text - in #macbook both works the same - also thx for your interest to help

Comment: @BGBruno You are welcome.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé system shortcuts are not always there in the shortcuts setting. Also, selecting has no item in any of the menus, so I don't know what text should I assign a shortcut to? Also, AFAIK, there's little difference in the two shifts at such usage level, so its hard to believe that your answer would fit well. P.S.: I didn't downvote..